# iOS UIWebView Size based on window

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I've got an app that uses a UIWebView. Currently I create the web view using a storyboard but I want to create it programatically.

This needs to work across all devices and iOS 5 - 7.

Currently (using the storyboard) in iOS 6 it looks like this:
[image: iPhone iOS 6]

But in iOS 7 you don't get that white bar at the top:
[image: iPhone iOS 7]

How can I create the UIWebView programatically so that it fills available window space (i.e. doesn't go over tab bar or status bar) across all devices?

Thanks

//EDIT
Here's my storyboard for the UIWebView

[image: UIWebView Storyboard]

//Edit 2

As per a suggestion I am doing this but it overlaps the status bar and tab bar. Is there any way to take them into account?

```
float width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; 
float height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
```

Comment: Status bar overlaps that white space it seems.

Comment: Please have a look on this link it may help you out http://ranga-iphone-developer.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-uiwebview-programmatically.html

Comment: @Ganapathy It doesn't - I've added an image of the storyboard

Comment: This allows creation of one web view - another thing I need to be able to do is have multiple web views and store them in an array. However some of the options on this do look useful so I'll give it a go. Thanks

Comment: So, basically you want the navigation bar?

Comment: @KyleFang I want to be able to programatically create a web view that doesn't overlap the tab bar or the status bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me based on others answers

```
-(void)createWebView
{
    float width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    float height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, width, height)];
    wv.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    wv.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    wv.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:wv];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set your webview's frame programmatically like this

```
float width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width; 
NSLog(@"width: %f", width);
float height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height; 
NSLog(@"height: %f", height);
```

so your webview's frame should be

```
objWeb.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);
```

Comment: This method doesn't take into account the tab bar and status bar

Comment: Is there a way to do it similarly to this but not overlapping those bars?

Comment: @ChrisByatt : it seems like you're using custom tabbar from your snapshots so i have no idea may be you need to check condition for 4 inch retina and 3.5 inch screens and accordingly set frame of a webview.

Comment: I just used the tab bar controller apple provides in a tabbed application. It looks different because the screenshot is iOS 7

Comment: okay just fixed up UIWebView's frame with condition of 3.5 or 4 inch screen may be that fixes your problem.

Comment: That doesn't account for iPad as well

Answer (score 0):

Okay, `self.view` will be resized at somewhere between `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.
So, if you wanted to adjust the size, you should do it in `viewWillApear`.

But, my suggestion is use `AutoResizeMask`, or `|[webView]|` for auto layout.

**AutoReszie**
add your `webView` to `self.view` as subView, set the frame to `self.view.boudse`, and then

```
webView.autoResizeMask = UIViewAutoResizeMaskFliexbleHeight|UIViewAutoResizeMaskFliexbleWidth;
```

let me know if you need autoLayout version.

Comment: This works for the tab bar but it still goes over the status bar

Comment: in iOS7 `UIViewController`'s view is stretched under the status bar, hot fix could be embed your viewController in a `UINavigationController` and set the shows Navigation bar to NO.

Comment: Using webView.scalePagesToFit = YES; solved the issue for me :) thanks for the help. See my answer below